# Creating multiple Gmail labels

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

Is there a way I can create multiple sub-labels instead of one by one?
I have created the following labels

```
-2015
  -January
    -3,4
    -10,11
    -17,18
    -24,25

  -February
    -31,1
    -7,8
    -14,15
    -21,22

etc.
```

Each label and sub-label is created individually, which is tedious work! I was wondering if there is a quicker way to add multiple sub-labels all at once, instead of creating *one* by *one* by *one*.

Comment: This might be doable using appscript, but back up and reconsider. Why are you trying to do this? It doesn't look like it will end happily

Comment: I am doing this for organizational reasons

Answer (score 6):

In straight-up Gmail, no, unfortunately not.

The only way I can think of to do it would be to get a third-party email client that supports IMAP and allows for quick folder creation like that. Then you could create the labels (folders) in that and get them in your Gmail account. You could always dump the client afterward.

Comment: What do you mean by "client" Plz elaborate on how to get this imap thing

Comment: A separate program for downloading/managing email. You know, like you used to need to do before there _was_ web-mail. Thunderbird is one such. So is Outlook (although it does a lot more). There are tons. Recommending one to use is outside the ken of this site.